# SeaBorn: Custom axes scaling & spines using PairPlot?

Tags: python, visualization, plotting

{ Figured this is the most germane place for this question, but definitely let me know if not! }

**Two Asks:**

1. How would I uniformly standardize the size and scale for each of the bivariate (i.e., scatter plots) "subplots" when using the PairPlot functionality in Seaborn (if the data is already standardized)? By default it creates the plots which are sized the same, but scaled differently.
2. Once the scale is uniform across all plots, I want all of the axes to be formatted such that each plot looks like a coordinate plane (i.e.,4 quadrants; both axes spines centered).

Here's some added context on my specific use case:

- I have z-scores for the World Series winning teams for a set of variables (ERA, R, Batting Avg., etc.)
- I want to plot all pairwise comparisons for this selected set of variables, and because all the data are already standardized, the axes should range roughly from [-3.5, 3.5].
- I'm less interested in regressions, and more interested in "archetypes" (e.g. 1995 Atlanta Braves had the best pitching in baseball but weren't exactly stellar hitters -- they still won the World Series! How many other WS winning teams would be in Quadrant III with them?)

Here's code I've used to make one such plot (not using Seaborn), but I want to take advantage of the power of doing as many pairwise comparison's as possible:

```
x = zscores_wswinners["teamBA"]
y = zscores_wswinners["ERA"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y)
plot_axes_range = [-3, 3, -3, 3]
ax.axis(plot_axes_range, 'equal')

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

ax.axhline(linewidth=1, color='black')
ax.axvline(linewidth=1, color='black')
plt.show()
```

(This seems pretty tedious, and PairPlot gets me 90%+ of the way to what I desire!)

Anyways, thanks, in advance!